# Could not find 'Use Docker Compose V2' check box to disable v2

Tags: docker

I could not run the containers and got this message:
Docker Compose is now in the Docker CLI, try `docker compose up`

ERROR: An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.
If you encounter this issue regularly because of slow network conditions, consider setting COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT to a higher value (current value: 60).

I guess it is because of turning Docker Compose V2 on automatically for Docker Desktop users

so, To disable Docker Compose V2 using Docker Desktop:

From the Docker menu, click Preferences (Settings on Windows) > General.
Clear the Use Docker Compose V2 check box. ---> did not find the check box

To disable Docker Compose V2 using the CLI, run:

docker-compose disable-v2 -------> No such command: disable_v2

Comment: docker versin 3.3.0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems for the options you mention you need to have Docker Desktop v3.2.1 and above ([new compose command](https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command/#install-on-mac-and-windows)).

I have the same problem on linux. It seems that I have downloaded docker-compose as a single binary (that later I placed in /usr/local/bin).

From the docker compose GitHub source:
[docker compose V2](https://github.com/docker/compose/tree/v2#about-update-and-backward-compatibility)
it seems that the V2 is **not** a single binary as in my (and I guess your) case. This is inspite getting v2.2.3 from

```
docker-compose --version
```

Thus I reckon that you have to install the new V2 compose as described in [Where to get Docker Compose](https://github.com/docker/compose/tree/v2#where-to-get-docker-compose) and then the functionality of switching between V1 and V2 will emerge.